# Comparing string differences to a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have a method, that computes the number of differences in two strings, and outputs where the differences are.

```
def method(a):
    count=0
    s1="ABC"
    for i in range (len(a)):
        if not a[i]==s1[i]:
            count=count+1
        else:
            count=count+0
    return a,count,difference(a, s1)
```

On input ex CBB, this method outputs

```
('CBB', 2, [1, 0, 1])
```

What I really need is for this method to do the same, but where is not only compares to a single string in s1, but to a list of strings

```
s1 = ['ACB', 'ABC', 'ABB']
```

Anyone with a smart method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `compare` function calculates the number of differences (and map of differences that you had been creating with `difference()`). I rewrote the compare function to take a base string to be compared to, `src`, so that you don't get stuck with comparing to `"ABC"` all the time.

```
def compare(src, test):
    if len(src) != len(test):
        return # must be the same length
    diffmap = [0]*len(src)
    count = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(src):
        if not c == test[i]:
            count = count+1
            diffmap[i] = 1
    return test, count, diffmap
```

The `compare_to_many` function simply goes through a list of strings to compare to, `srcs`, and creates a list of the comparisons between those base strings and a test string `test`.

```
def compare_to_many(srcs, test):
    return map(lambda x: compare(x, test), srcs)
```

### EDIT:

After clarification in the comments, @X-Pender needs the source list to be hardcoded. This can be reflected by the following, single function:

```
def compare(test):
    def compare_one(src, test):
        diffmap = [0]*len(src)
        count = 0
        for i, c in enumerate(src):
        if not c == test[i]:
            count = count+1
            diffmap[i] = 1
        return test, count, diffmap
    sources = ["ABC", "CDB", "EUA"] # this is your hardcoded list
    return map(lambda x: compare_one(x, test), sources)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after clarification, instead of hardcoding s1, make your method take it as argument:

```
def method(a, s1):
    count=0
    for i in range (len(a)):
        if not a[i]==s1[i]:
            count=count+1
        else:
            count=count+0
    return a,count,difference(a, s1)
```

Then use list compherension:

```
 result = [method(a, s1) for s1 in list]
```

Be careful though, as your method will fail if a is longer than s1. As you really don't say what the result should be in that case, i left it as is.

Comment: this compares multiple test strings to a single base string, but what X-Pender wants is to compare one test string to multiple base strings.

Comment: The function should only take one argument, and the list is supposed to be hardcoded.

Comment: Any reason why? You can always just pass in the same list everytime you call the function

Comment: @X-Pender then rename it method2, leave method signature as is and call method2 from method.

Comment: @soulcheck The reason is just that this is the way the assignment was put to me. But maybe there is a better way than "rerouting" the problem formulation by making 2 methods? The method may be rewritten as you like.

Comment: You should mention in your question that it's a homework assignment. It's not cool to let other people do your homework without telling them.

Comment: I have already solved the exercise, I just wanted a better/more pretty solution, than the has I made my self.